# concatenar con valores nulos en mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo lo siguiente:

```
|ap_pat|ap_mat|pri_nombre|seg_nom|

|Jara  |Rios  |Luis      |ivan   |

|lopez |NULL  |Jorge     |alf    |
```

Al concatenar con `CONCAT` o `CONCAT_WS` me da un espacio de mas entre cada dato si esta `NULL` me lo muestra asi:

```
Jara Rios Luis Ivan

Lopez |*| Jorge Alf
```

Ven que el segundo valor muestra un espacio de mas `|*|` entre `ap_pat` y `nombre` como lo puedo hacer para que omita ese espacio

Comment: Hola Francisco, por añade la(s) consulta(s) SQL que probastes. Puedes utilizar el enlace [editar](http://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/52767/edit) para hacer esto

Answer (score 4):

Hay algo que no has explicado bien, porque el uso de `CONCAT_WS` con un separador  `' '` debería funcionar perfectamente.  Por ejemplo, si hacemos la consulta siguiente:

```
select concat_ws(' ', 'Lopez', null, 'Jorge', 'alf');
```

El resultado es (<kbd>[**Demo**](http://rextester.com/EZZM62277)</kbd>):

```
Lopez Jorge alf
```

... sin ningún espacio adicional.

<kbd>[**Demo más completo**](http://rextester.com/LQIYZ28013)</kbd>

Mi sospecha es que donde piensas que tienes un `NULL` en realidad tienes una cadena vacía. En ese caso sí te agregaría un espacio de más.

Por ejemplo, si modificamos la consulta a:

```
select concat_ws(' ', 'Lopez', '', 'Jorge', 'alf');
```

Entonces el resultado es (<kbd>[**Demo**](http://rextester.com/XESTT29018)</kbd>):

```
Lopez  Jorge alf
```

... ahora sí con un espacio adicional.

Comment: y como lo harias para colocar los campos en vez de los nombre 'Lopez' ap_pat y si estos fueran null, igual agrega un espacio

Comment: Hola Francisco. Que tal si comienzas por incluir tu consulta en tu pregunta como te comenté bajo tu pregunta.

Comment: Pero para contestar a tu duda, funcionaría de forma idéntica. Aquí puedes verlo: http://rextester.com/LQIYZ28013. Como te digo, hay algo incompleto en tu pregunta, porque `CONCAT_WS` funciona perfectamente.

Comment: De hecho, te sugiero de hacer como yo hice. O sea, prepara un [mcve] usando http://rextester.com/l/mysql_online_compiler o cualquier otra herramiento del mismo estilo para que podamos reproducir tu problema sin tener que adivinar lo que está pasando.

Comment: tienes razon agradecido, revise los valores de la tabla y por determinado esta null pero algunos campos estaban en blanco y los reconocia como valor y no null

Comment: @Francisco No olvides aceptar esta respuesta si es la que mejor soluciona tu problema.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar la función `IFNULL` de MySQL. Con esta función puedes retornar un valor alternativo si el dato es `NULL`:

```
SELECT
    CONCAT( IFNULL(CONCAT(ap_pat, ' '), ''),
        IFNULL(CONCAT(ap_mat, ' '), ''),
        IFNULL(CONCAT(pri_nombre, ' '), ''),
        IFNULL(seg_nom, '') )

FROM tabla;
```

En este ejemplo, si alguno de los apellidos o nombres es `NULL`, mostrará una cadena vacía para ese dato.

Comment: lo realice como lo indicaste pero aun asi me da un espacio de mas sino existe el apellido materno  Perez    JUAN

Comment: @Francisco Cierto, ahora noté mi error: Incluí un espacio de más después de cada columna. Lo acabo de corregir.